# fiducials on a panel

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

have a little question about fiducials:

My Layouter/My Boss likes to use 3 fiducials on the panelframe and one fiducial on each individual board in the panel.

My job is to build the program for the pick&place mounter and to produce the boards.

I prefere 3 "global" fiducials on each individual board in the panel. 3 or 2 fiducials on the panelframe ist ok for printing.

What is the better way to do this (I think its my way) and what are the arguments for the better way, so i can convince my layouter.

Thanks for your help in advance

Reelf

edit:

Thank you, friends, for your comments and hints!

Meanwhile I have done some more research on my own.

And I found, that, if I have 2 or 3 global marks on the individual boards, it is possible to get the best results of correction of shrink, stretch, offsets and warpage through the automatic correction algorythms of the mounter.

If I have only panel fiducials and maybe only one fiducial on each individual board, this automatic correction works badly.

Thanks a lot and a good time for you all!

Comment: http://www.accutroninc.com/pdf/download/fiducial.pdf

Comment: That seems kind of strange. Normally your global fiducials are going to stay the same from panel to panel. Having only a single fiducial per board won't allow the pick and place to determine which board it's looking at.

Comment: The way most EE's would do it is, "ask the guy who has to program the pick & place machine". Maybe your boss used to have your job and knows some trick to programming the machine for fewer fiducials that he can teach you?